# Adding onclick event to td, but should not fire on links within

Tags: jquery, events, onclick, propagation

I have this:

```
$('table.data td').click(function() {
}
```

But the problem is this also fires when I click on links within that column. How can I prevent that?

Tried something like `table.data td :not(a)` but that doesn't seem to work at all..

Thanks.

--

Nevermind, just found out about e.target.nodeName! (if that is the best way to deal with this: != 'A')

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can stop the event propagation for the children nodes this way:

```
$('table.data td a').click(function(evt){
  evt.stopPropagation();
  [.. Do other stuff ..]
});
```

[jquery stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) *Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.*